# how to stop record after x seconds with Twilio during an outboud call?

Tags: twilio, call, recording

i want to record an outgoing call on twilio and stop it after x seconds
everything works except the timeout or maxlength
i have two files: 
makecall.php

```
to_number = "+33123456789";
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->account->calls->create(
    $to_number,
    $twilio_number,
    array(
"record" => True, 
"maxLength" => 30,
"RecordingStatusCallback" => "callback.php",
"Url" => "answercall.php"
    )
);
```

answercall.php

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;
$response = new VoiceResponse();
$response->record(['maxLength' => 30]);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;;
```

i also tried in answercall

```php
$response->pause(['length' => 30]);
$response->hangup();
```

but it doesnt stop recording !

Answer (score 0):

maxLength is an attribute of the TwiML [Record Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) rather then being an attribute of the [Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call).

You will need to use Recording API for this purpose.

Reference [Stop a call Recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording?code-sample=code-stop-a-call-recording&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x).

Comment: Ok i used $response->record([ 'maxLength' => 20, 'recordingStatusCallback' => '.... to stop the recording but how to make the call stop after X seconds ?